# How to handle DbUpdateConcurrencyException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency

I have an endpoint which hits two functions based on query parameter. There is a use case where this endpoint will hit simultaneously and due to that I am running into concurrency issue. To avoid this, I have added retry logic but looks like it is not working as expected.

I am getting the following error while updating the same cosmos document (`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`).

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Conflicts were detected for item with id 'ABC123'.

What am I doing wrong here?
What is the best approach to handle this scenario on large volume? (i.e., >15K-20K request per hour)

Approach:

- Trigger endpoints to hit the cosmos at the same time with same partition key.
- Add retry logic (using `Polly`) in case of `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.
- Prior to retry, `stop tracking all currently tracked entities` and then move forward.
- My retry attempts are 3 times, every 250 ms.

Code:

Service.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Polly;
using Polly.Retry;

namespace Services
{

    public class SpecificationsService : ServiceBase, ISpecificationsService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SpecificationsService> _logger;
        private readonly IManageSpecifications _manageSpecifications;
        // private readonly AsyncRetryPolicy _policy = Policy
        //     .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
        //     .WaitAndRetryAsync(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.MaxRetryAttempt, _ =>  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.RetryInterval));

        private readonly AsyncRetryPolicy _policy = Policy
            .Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()
            .RetryAsync(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.MaxRetryAttempt,
                (_, _) => Task.Delay(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.RetryInterval));
            
        private int _retryAttempt;

        public SpecificationsService(ILogger<SpecificationsService> logger, IManageSpecifications manageSpecifications)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _manageSpecifications = manageSpecifications;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertMotorSpecificationsAsyncWithRetryAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => UpsertMotorSpecificationsAsync(myDto, ct), cancellationToken);
        }
        
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertMotorSpecificationsAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var materializedEntity = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.GetDataEntityByIdAsync(myDto.Vin, cancellationToken);

                EntityEntry<MaterializedEntity> materializedEntityEntry;

                if (materializedEntity == null)
                {
                    materializedEntityEntry = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.AddMaterializedEntityAsync(materializedEntityToCreate, cancellationToken);
                    response.StatusCode = ResultCode.Created;
                }
                else
                {
                    materializedEntityEntry = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.UpdateMaterializedEntity(materializedEntity);
                    response.StatusCode = ResultCode.Updated;
                }

                if (await _manageSpecifications.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) > 0)
                {
                    response.Result = myDto;
                }
                else
                    return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                _manageSpecifications.ClearAsync();
                _retryAttempt++;
                
                if (_retryAttempt.Equals(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.MaxRetryAttempt))
                {
                    return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>();
                }

                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertAtdSpecificationsWithRetryAsync(MyDto myDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => UpsertAtdSpecificationsAsync(myDto, ct), cancellationToken);
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<MyDto>> UpsertAtdSpecificationsAsync(MyDto myDto,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var materializedEntity = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.GetDataEntityByIdAsync(myDto.Vin, cancellationToken);

                EntityEntry<MaterializedEntity> materializedEntityEntry;

                if (materializedEntity == null)
                {
                    materializedEntityEntry = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.AddMaterializedEntityAsync(materializedEntityToCreate, cancellationToken);
                    response.StatusCode = ResultCode.Created;
                }
                else
                {
                    materializedEntityEntry = await _manageSpecifications.MyRepository.UpdateMaterializedEntity(materializedEntity);
                    response.StatusCode = ResultCode.Updated;
                }

                if (await _manageSpecifications.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) > 0)
                {
                    response.Result = myDto;
                }
                else
                    return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                _manageSpecifications.ClearAsync();
                _retryAttempt++;
                
                if (_retryAttempt.Equals(MasterDataConstants.RetryOnConcurrencyException.MaxRetryAttempt))
                {
                    return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>();
                }

                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return GetExceptionServiceResponse<MyDto>(exception.GetBaseException().Message);
            }
        }
        
      }
}
```

Repo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Cosmos.UnitsOfWork
{
    public interface IManageSpecifications : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public IMyRepository MyRepository { get; }

        void ClearAsync();
    }

    public class ManageSpecifications: IManageSpecifications
    {
        private IMyRepository? _MyRepository;

        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

        public IMyRepository MyRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyRepository ??= new SomeRepository(_dbContext);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Overloaded Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbContextFactory">Instance of IDbContextFactory</param>
        public ManageSpecifications(IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(DbContext));
        }

        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public void ClearAsync()
        {
             _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
        }
        
        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Conflicts were detected for item with id 'ABC123'.
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: Conflict (409); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 7b3c8312-9108-402b-b22e-b0c5cc036903; Reason: (
code : Conflict
message : Entity with the specified id already exists in the system.
```

Comment: Do you generate the keys or is your db?

Comment: I think the issue is in ``Business logic`` that you didn't share.

Comment: You should keep in mind that after the first attempt the `DbContext` instance is dirty and you do the next two attempts with the same dirty `DbContext` instance.

Comment: "Prior to retry, stop tracking all currently tracked entities" I don't see that anywhere in the code. Either way, a concurrency exception isn't really recoverable unless you reload all the data and redo your calculations. You are not supposed to have multiple contexts working on the same rows at the same time. Otherwise you are going to need another form of locking, such as setting the row to `Processing` state or similar.

Comment: @DanielA.White In this container, `vin` is the partition key and `id` holds the same value. I am assigning those values.

Comment: @SirRufo I am stopping all tracking entities by using `_manageSpecifications.ClearAsync();` which internally is `_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Charlieface That is under `catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbUpdateConcurrencyException)` where I am mentioning `_manageSpecifications.ClearAsync();` which is `_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();`. Shouldn't that be suffice?

Comment: Asuuming it's actually `async` shouldn't it be `await _manageSpecifications.ClearAsync();` ?

Comment: @Charlieface It is bad naming, I'll address it. But it is just `_dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();` which is void, so. I have that under `Repo.cs` in my code above.

Comment: @GThree Not really a problem, but I tend to dispose that DbContext and use a fresh one for the retry operation because I faced some issues in the past. Just wanted to be sure that you address it.